# Infinite Loop in Python using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this piece of code (pygame) I get an infinite loop. Can someone explain this to me? I have tried fixing the while loop but nothing seems to happen.

[image: 1]

Comment: After `sys.exit()` add `break`.

Comment: Please paste your code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score -1):

I think the True condition is always the same, you need to change it to false after something happens. I recommend creating a variable with the value true and changing to false after something happens